# Print statement with .format results in error

Tags: ipython, jupyter-notebook

I have following `print` statement:-

```
print("{0:0.2f}% in traing set".format((len(X_train)/(df.index))*100))
```

where

```
X_train = is 70% of sample data(training data)
```

and

```
df.index is RangeIndex(start=0, stop=768, step=1)
```

when I run print statement I get error as follow

```
non-empty format string passed to object.__format__
```

Answer of the print statement should be

```
69.92 in training set
30.08 in test set
```

I am not able to correct this behavior.
Any help will be appreciated.

Bharat.

Comment: What do you get with `print(len(X_train)/(df.index))*100)`; just a plain print of the value without special formatting?

Comment: I was able to resolve it! I followed your code below! Thanks.

Comment: I was able to solve the problem with rewriting the print statement:-value1 =  len(X_train)
value2 =  len(X_test)
value3 =  len(df.index)

value4 = (value1/value3)*100
value5 = (value2/value3)*100

print("{0:0.2f}% in training set".format(value4))
print("{0:0.2f}% in test set".format(value5))

Answer (score 0):

I get this error if the object that's supposed to be formatted is a numpy array.  `RangeIndex()` must be producing something similar.

```
In [82]: "{0:0.2f}% in traing set".format((20/(np.arange(3)))*100)
...
TypeError: non-empty format string passed to object.__format__
In [83]:
```

Same error if I just give it a list: `"{0:0.2f}% in traing set".format([1,2,3])`

Formatting works fine if the argument is just a number:

```
In [83]: "{0:0.2f}% in traing set".format((20/3)*100)
Out[83]: '666.67% in traing set'
```

The only `format` specifier that works with an object like a list or array is the plain str/repr,

```
In [102]: print("{} in traing set".format((len(X_train)/(np.arange(1,3)))*100))
[ 5000.  2500.] in traing set
```

===============

It's hard to read code in a comment; better to add it as an edit to the original question (clearly marked as such).  Here's my guess as to what the formatting is:

```
value1 = len(X_train) 
value2 = len(X_test) 
value3 = len(df.index) 
value4 = (value1/value3)*100 
value5 = (value2/value3)*100 
print("{0:0.2f}% in training set".format(value4)) 
print("{0:0.2f}% in test set".format(value5))
```

Yes, it is a good idea to separate the calculation of the values from the print formatting.

Comment: I was able to solve the problem with rewritting the print statement:-